# Powershell context menu shortcuts such as CTRL+M don't work

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, powershell

I often use the mark function in powershell. The context menu says that the short-cut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>.

[image: Powershell Mark shortcut]

However, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> doesn't seem to work. It just inputs `^M`. The strange thing is that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> does work and does not print anything.

In the context menu properties I've enabled ctrl key shortcuts.

[image: cltr key shortcuts]

I've also tried disabling it, to no avail. There does not seem to be much more I can do. How do I get the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> shortcut to work in powershell? (The alternative is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> which does work but isn't really userfriendly)

Comment: Any luck ? Same thing here

Comment: @FabioMarreco unfortunately I never got this to work :(.

Comment: Doesn't work with PowerShell, but does work in CMD shell.

Comment: It increases the chance to solve it if you upvote this bug report in  Windows 10  feedbackhub app (search for "PowerShell console : context menu  shortcuts such as CTRL+F don't work")

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a workaround - but it works for me:

At the Powershell prompt, type cmd, hit enter - this will launch command prompt - then ctrl+m works. When you are done you can type "exit" and it will return to powershell.